# How to convert scanned document images to a PDF document with high compression?

Tags: pdf

I need to convert scanned document images to a PDF document with high compression. Compression ratio is very important. Can someone recommend any solution on C# for this task?

Best regards, Alexander

Answer (score 0):

There is a free program called PDFBeads that can do it. It requires Ruby, ImageMagick and optionally jbig2enc.

Answer (score -1):

The PDF format itself will probably add next to no overhead in your case. I mean your images will account for most of the output file size.

So, you should compress your images with highest possible compression. For black-and-white images you might get smallest output using FAX4 or JBIG2 compression schemes (both supported in PDF files).

For other images (grayscale, color) either use smallest possible size, lowest resolution and quality, or convert images to black-and-white and use FAX4/JBIG2 compression scheme.

Please note, that most probably you will lose some detail of any image while converting to black-and-white.

If you are looking for a library that can help you with recompression then have a look at [Docotic.Pdf library](https://bitmiracle.com/pdf-library/) (Disclaimer: I am one of developers of the library).

The [Optimize images](https://github.com/BitMiracle/Docotic.Pdf.Samples/tree/master/Samples/Compression/OptimizeImages) sample code shows how to recompress images before adding them to PDF. The sample shows how to recompress with JPEG, but for FAX4 the code will be almost the same.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. I searched the internet and have found that PDF MRC technology may suit my needs. PDF MRC technology separates the image into components with different levels of compressability and uses the most efficient and accurate compression algorithm  for each image component. Does your library support PDF MRC? At the moment I am evaluating products from LeadTools, Abbyy and VintaSoft.

Comment: @alexangr MRC looks very promising in your case. Unfortunately, there is no support for this technology in Docotic.Pdf yet.

Comment: Do NOT use JBIG2: http://www.dkriesel.com/en/blog/2013/0802_xerox-workcentres_are_switching_written_numbers_when_scanning